# Show but disable wysiwyg buttons

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm running CKEditor in an environment where permissions dictate the level of content editing you have. One requirement is for the buttons to show for everyone, but certain button's click events disabled.

I've tried a many jQuery solutions (attr, off, preventDefault, prop, etc) but none of them work, at least how I tried them.

Sample HTML generated by CKFinder, the 'add image' button:

```
<a id="cke_22" 
    class="cke_button cke_button__image cke_button_off " "="" 
    href="javascript:void('Image')" title="Image" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_22_label" aria-haspopup="false" 
    onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(56,event);" 
    onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(57,event);" 
    onmousedown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(58,event);" 
    onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(59,this);return false;">

    <span class="cke_button_icon cke_button__image_icon">&nbsp;</span>
    <span id="cke_22_label" class="cke_button_label cke_button__image_label">Image</span>
</a>
```

I can't find a CKEditor solution in their docs, but I may have missed something. I'm open to a fix outside of CKEditor if some extra Javascript can break the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use CKEditor API to do this right. Disabling buttons by jQuery is a bad idea, because this way you won't block keyboard shortcuts, context menu positions and you will also break the a11y features (e.g. navigating the toolbar with keyboard will be broken).

To disable e.g. **link** and **image** features use this code:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    on: {
        loaded: function( evt ) {
            var editor = evt.editor;

            editor.getCommand( 'image' ).on( 'state', function() {
                this.disable();
            } );
            editor.getCommand( 'link' ).on( 'state', function() {
                this.disable();
            } );
        }
    }
} );
```

It makes sure that on every state change command is disabled.

Tip: if you are unsure what's the name of the command that you want to disable, check the `editor.commands` object which may give you some ideas.

Comment: This is a much better solution.

Comment: This makes sense but I'm having a tough time. CKEDITOR returns data but editor.commands is showing as empty. The getCommand docs aren't too helpful. I can post a new question if I'm not doing something obviously stupid.

Comment: The `editor` is not a global variable. You need to get it from `CKEDITOR.instances` object, or like I did in my answer, from `evt.editor` in one of event listeners.

Comment: Got this worked out! Looks like CK4 is a bit different than 3. I used `ev.editor.commands.justifyleft.disable();` where justifyleft is from the command list. I do have a follow up question but I'll mark this accepted since it got me there!

Answer (score 0):

If it is enough for you, using image as an example, you could just simply nuke all the handlers. I don't know if CKE actually restores them periodically, but if not you could do something like this

```
jQuery('.cke_button__image')
    .attr('onkeydown','')
    .attr('onmousedown','')
    .attr('onclick','');
```

It works in the CKEditor demo. If the attributes reappear, just repeat the procedure. Note that this is not a real security answer. Any half-decent hacker will easily go around limitations like these but it will fill your recuirements.