# Buttons Re-Enable in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have the following Javascript to disable buttons on CKEditor:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'text', {
    on : {
        instanceReady : function(ev) {
            ev.editor.commands.image.disable();
            ev.editor.commands.justifyleft.disable();
        }
    }
});
```

This works well to disable the buttons on load, but on click of any other non-disabled buttons, they all re-enable. I tried placing the code in a few other places but had no luck.

Where is the correct place to place the disable code so it won't re-enable?

Comment: Not very familiar with CKEditor, but according to http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar there must be a config file. That looks the best place for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to disable buttons, not hide them, then check my answer in - [Show but disable wysiwyg buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582226/show-but-disable-wysiwyg-buttons/15598583#15598583).

If you want to remove them completely then check this guide - http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_toolbar